# ¿Hay otra palabra o frase para expresar 'muestreo aleatorio'?

Tags: matemáticas, ciencia

Creo que escuché a alguien referise a un *muestreo aleatorio* con otra palabra, pero ya no me acuerdo cuál era...  ¿Hay otra forma de expresar el mismo concepto matemático?

Comment: "muestra aleatoria" es estándard. No recuerdo haber escuchado sinónimos. Ten en cunta que en matemáticas (así como en el resto de las ciencias "duras") los sinónimos no son algo deseable. `Un concepto <-> Una palabra`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Muestreo aleatorio" es estándar en estadística, tanto en las ciencias puras como en las ciencias sociales.

Un sinónimo posible es "muestreo al azar".

Es necesario mencionar que existe también otro sinónimo de aleatorio que es "randomizado": se trata de un anglicismo innecesario, porque, como muy bien dice *belisarius* en su comentario, la sinonimia no es deseable en el lenguaje científico. Lo ideal es la correspondencia biunívoca entre término y concepto. Me opongo al uso de "randomizado", que considero inaceptable, pero existe, aunque por suerte se use poco y no haya conseguido desplazar al término "aleatorio".

Nota: no es buena idea escribir "estándard" (con "d" final, como hace *belisarius*), ni "estandar" (sin acento, como hace *ChairOTP*). Lo mejor en español es "estándar", como propone la Real Academia y defienden todos los manuales de lenguaje científico.

Comment: Tienes razon.  Es preferible no confundirse entre conceptos bien complicadas.

Comment: A lo mejor hay otros terminos para 'muestreo aleatorio' que provienen de otros campos?  negocio? politica?

Comment: @Paul No que yo sepa, Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Concuerdo con belisarius al decir que la palabra "muestreo aleatorio" es estandar a las matemáticas. Son términos generalizados que usualmente no tienen sinónimos.